# Complicated Mysql Database Joins

Tags: php, mysql, join

I'm creating a new system using an old database and need some help (because of inexperience)
This might be overly complicated but that's how the database is setup and I cannot change it.

There are 3 tables. Session 1, Session 2, and Registrants.

Session 1 and Session 2 are the same apart from content. So how it worked was that if a person wanted to book session 1 and session 2 on a specific day, the database would insert say "5" in both session 1's and session 2's 'id' rows. 'id' is the primary index.

There are 2 rows in 'Registrants' that contains a list (ex. 5,6,7) that contains the registrant names and some of the id's found in session 1 and session 2. So if you wanted to know if the person booked for session 1, the session's id would be in the registrants session 1 list.

Like I said. complicated.

I can do separate queries without trouble with

```
SELECT * FROM Session_1 WHERE id IN ($registrant_session_1 /* This is a single quote implode for the ouput of registrant_session_1 */ )"
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM Session_2 WHERE id IN ($registrant_session_2 /* This is a single quote implode for the ouput of registrant_session_2 */)
```

I need help with creating a query that joins them for simultaneous output. So the theory is that I first do the session checks and then join them based on the id's.

Comment: Is there any way that you can merge the two tables together and then key them by type of content? At the moment, it doesn't seem as if you have a healthy setup.

Comment: Can you clarify how you want your output to look like?

Comment: Lets say. Id, Session 1 (yes/no), Session 2 (yes/no). They need to be joined otherwise the results will be mixed.

Comment: Rebuilding the database is an option only If there is no way that I can join the results based on identical id's. It will take a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use "union" clause
`FROM Session_1 WHERE Session_1.id IN ($registrant_session_1 /* This is a single quote implode for the ouput of registrant_session_1 */ ) UNION (SELECT * FROM Session_2 WHERE Session_2.id IN ($registrant_session_2 /* This is a single quote implode for the ouput of registrant_session_2 */)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site I found particularly useful when I was first learning MySQL http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqljoins.php